# Turn on crash-dump at windows crash

Tags: windows-7, crash, minidumps

This morning, my computer was turned off. I usually leave it on at night, so this must have been a crash. Starting the computer confirmed this: Windows did not shut down normally.

Later today, I went downstairs for dinner. When I got back about 30 minutes later, the computer was turned off again. And once again: Windows did not shut down normally.

The problem is that windows isn't generating any dumps. I went and checked advanced settings and it's set to do a kernel dump, but the file isn't there.

I then checked for all files ending in .DMP, which turned up nothing.

The Event Viewer isn't helping either. It just says that at a certain time, Windows was shut down in a bad way... no details.

So, I need to find a way to turn on the creation of a mini-dump, if I'm ever going to be able to analyze this. Given that the advanced settings are set to make the dump, but they're not doing it, what else can I do?

Edit: my machine is a HP Pavilion dv7 laptop. Running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1.

EDIT2: screenshot of my advanced settings on the matter:
[image]

Comment: If the system had crashed, it would have restarted, not shut down.  Try checking for hardware problems, such as an overheating CPU.

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe it won't make a dump if a power problem.

Comment: Who OS are you using? Do you have the check mark for automaticly restart? It could be hardware, have you ran a hardware diagnostic tool? If you don't know how to, what brand is your computer? Where are you searching for the *.dmp file? I usually check the whole computer, some times it puts it in a user folder, some times it puts it in the c:\windows\minidump folder.

Comment: @Nixphoe: Automatic restart is unchecked. I'm searching for the *.dmp file on the entire C drive. @DragonLord: Event Viewer has 0 Hardware events logged.

Comment: What brand of computer are you using? Dell, HP, home made?

Comment: @Nixphoe: The minidump folder doesn't seem to exist here... Also, reload page, I added some info to the question.

Comment: if its a hardware problem windows wouldn't make a crash dump. Check your power supply and temperatures

Comment: @acme64: I don't really know what you mean by that. Is there a log kept somewhere of temperatures on shutdown? And like I said: I wasn't at my laptop when the it shut down.

Comment: oh it's a laptop. Does your battery charge ok? it might be going bad and turning off the system if there isn't enough juice. Can your laptop power on with just the AC plug and no battery? try it like that for a bit and see if it still shuts down.

Comment: @acme: yes, it's actually brand new and almost constantly hooked to the AC.

Answer (score 1):

As of generic help for windows, the MiniDump can be enabled under the system properties.

For XP Right Click on my computer->properties->advanced Settings->Advanced->Startup and Recovery to see your options.

For 7 Right Click on Computer->properties->advanced Settings->Advanced->Startup and Recovery to see your options.

As other posts have said, however, this may not help you.

Comment: @Jeff_F.: Added a screenshot